# What happened to Butler's car?

Tags: design, navigation

Having read the [article](http://books.google.com/books?id=jd8DAAAAMBAJ&lpg=PA128&dq=automatic%20car&pg=PA128#v=onepage&q&f=false) "This Car Has Electric Brains" in Popular Mechanics, August 1958 I have some questions.

How practical were his methods? Was his work acquired by a car manufacturer or some other company? Were his methods developed further?

How did his corner navigation work? I don't think he needed to know the distances of road segments; I think he could have used sonar or radar to detect a corner but if cars were entering the corner before him, he could misinterpret those cars as a wall and the absence of a corner. Additionally I think he'd need two sonar/radar systems on both sides of the cars which aren't mentioned; all that's mentioned is a set of relays.

What is the compensator that is mentioned (it's said to function as a gyroscope)? I cannot find any information on this device (that I'm sure is relevant).

Comment: This question seems a little broad. Are you just looking for an article with more information on this vehicle?

Comment: You could say that. I am looking for more information about it, and I noted some of the questions I have above.